# Remove certain fields from the mongoose HydratedDocument

Tags: typescript, mongoose

When we lean the documents, the `id` property is still included which is undefined and can cause unexpected errors.

To simplify this for my team, I want to remove the `id` field from the HydratedDocument in the custom types.

```
// @types/mongoose/index.d.ts

import 'mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument as _Hydra, Document as _Docu } from 'mongoose';

declare module 'mongoose' {
  export type HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals> = Omit<_Hydra<T>, 'id' | '__v'>;
```

```
// tsconfig.json
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "@types"]
```

It is still not working for me. When I import the typing and try to declare a variable. Then I found that actually `id` property is coming from Document class. Following is the updated typings

```
import 'mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument as _Hydra, Document as _Docu } from 'mongoose';

declare module 'mongoose' {
  export type HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals> = Omit<_Hydra<T>, 'id' | '__v'>;
  export class Document implements Omit<_Docu, 'id'> {}
}
```

Unfortunately, this is also not working.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to overwrite/remove properties from type definition, which sadly is not possible

Comment: Ohk but can I create my own type then like `HydratedDocument2` or `Document2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. But there is a hack which I am currently using

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

type _MongooseDoc<T> = Document<unknown, any, T> & T & { _id: ObjectId };

export type MongooseDoc<T> = Omit<_MongooseDoc<T>, '__v' | 'id'>;

export type MongooseRef<T> = MongooseDoc<T> | string | ObjectId;

export type MongooseLean<T> = Omit<MongooseDoc<T>, keyof Document<unknown, any, T>> & { _id: ObjectId };
```